# How to make new field of custom object reportable in salesforce?

Tags: reporting

How to make a new field of custom object reportable in salesforce? I don't see any custom field while I was trying to create a report. How do I add it to the report?

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to add the new custom field to the Report Type that your Report belongs to. For example, if you had a Report Type of "Cases with Account", that Report Type will have a list of selected fields for each object type in the report.

You can update your report types by going to Setup > Feature Settings > Analytics > Reports & Dashboards > Report Types. There you will see a list of your report types, select the report type used by your report, scroll to the bottom where you can see Fields Available for Reports, and finally select Edit Layout to update the selected fields.